# Is there a term for games with overly precise controls?

Tags: terminology

There have been a bunch of recent games that feature controls that feature overly precise controls, for the sake of humor, challenge, or both. The player typically controls individual muscles or body parts rather than simply pressing buttons to perform actions. Such games include:

- [Surgeon Simulator 2013](http://store.steampowered.com/app/233720/)
- [QWOP](http://www.foddy.net/Athletics.html)
- [Probably Archery](http://store.steampowered.com/app/263420/)
- [Ampu-Tea](http://store.steampowered.com/app/289090/)
- [Toribash](http://www.toribash.com/)

Is there a term specifically for this type of game?

Comment: Voting to reopen as per community consensus at: [Do we want to change our policy on “Is There a Term for X?” questions?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15942/4797)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be an "official" term for these.  They're almost certainly a subset of the "simulation" genre, but the formal term depends on who you ask.

Octodad's Twitter account suggested ["awkward-like"](https://twitter.com/octodadgame/status/327037296102764545).

This was part of a Twitter conversation around a [Gamasutra article](https://twitter.com/RaveofRavendale/status/327071233030123520), where some other suggestions were made like "clumsimulation," "limb-disentanglers," and "QWOPlikes."

I'm personally fond of ["bumblecore"](https://twitter.com/KevinZuhn/status/327098956440027139) myself, which was suggested by one of the Octodad designers.